# how to convert html in to sencha touch

Tags: html, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have this pure code in HTML

```
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="load()"> 
    <div>
     <input type="text" id="addressInput" size="10"/>
    <select id="radiusSelect">
      <option value="25" selected>25mi</option>
      <option value="100">100mi</option>
      <option value="200">200mi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" onclick="searchLocations()" value="Search"/>
    </div>
    <div><select id="locationSelect" style="width:100%;visibility:hidden"></select></div>
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 80%"></div>
  </body>
```

what i am trying in **sencha Touch 2** is

```
items: [{
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    title: 'Search Stores',

                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            name : 'name',
                            label: 'Adress',
                            placeHolder: 'Enter City & State or ZIP code'
                        },
                       {
                            xtype: 'selectfield',
                            label: 'Radius:',
                            options: [
                                {text: '25mi',  value: '25'},
                                {text: '100mi', value: '100'},
                                {text: '200mi',  value: '200'}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
            }]
```

Actually I am working on finding the store using **sencha touch 2** and i follow this link 
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

this works fine for me but this code is not sufficient, now i want to know how can i call this from sencha touch 2 `onload="load()`,  `onclick="searchLocations()"`, `visibility:hidden`
I read the documentation of sencha touch but not able to do that any help is highly appreciated

Comment: do you want the equivalent code of your html in sencha touch ?

Comment: @roadRunner Yes and after this i follow again this link https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3 and find the store using sencha touch 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's equivalent code of your HTML in Sencha touch

- `<input type="button" onclick="searchLocations()" value="Search"/>`

  ```
   {
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Search',
    ui: 'confirm',
    listeners : {
        tap : function() {
          // body of searchLocations()
        }
    }
   }
  ```
- For `visibility:hidden`, use the following property of `selectfield`

  ```
   hidden: true
  ```
- For `onload="load()"`, you can call following method of Component.

  ```
   initialize()
  ```

Comment: and for body onload="load()" ??

Comment: right now i have not any question if occurs i ask later thanks